# BottomNavigation Fragment state

Tags: android

I have a BottomNavigation implemented in my app. when i tap on navigation items it shows their respective fragments, it is working fine. I have implemented a progress bar in every fragment so whenever i select a fragment from BottomNavigation the progress bar displays, my question is when i select any option from BottomNavigation progress bar shows then fragments load but when the fragment is loaded it should gets saved when i come back to that option from BottomNavigation it loads again... is there any way to save the state of that fragment so that it only loads for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onSavedInstanceState(Bundle)` This will get you the required behavior, so this method is called before an activity may be killed so that when it comes back some time in the future it can restore its state.

Here i use activity which in respect is any activity, even if its a fragment, this example is from the official documentation.

For example, if activity B is launched in front of activity A, and at some point activity A is killed to reclaim resources, activity A will have a chance to save the current state of its user interface via this method so that when the user returns to activity A, the state of the user interface can be restored via `onCreate(Bundle)` or `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`.

check out this cool link, it describes everything and a little bit more: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en